# Memory leak caused by Power Query'd .xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba, macos, memory-leaks, powerquery

I have a memory leak caused by a particular file interacting with this code.

The macro opens all .xlsx files in a particular directly, copies the sheets into my active workbook, then closes them.

I've run this on a number of .xlsx as well as .csv files with no issues. However, when I run it on the pertinent data, it results in my Excel memory usage spiking to 4GB and then steadily climbing (clearly a leak of some sort).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Combine_Zoho_Gusto()

Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Path = "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Payroll Analysis" & "\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

The .xlsx file I'm trying to get this to run on is using Power Query, which points to a folder which contains a .csv file. The Power Query filters and organizes this data into two columns of data with headers which it then displays on its sole Sheet1.

The command that causes the memory to spike:

```
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Update:
I've been exploring my data in the power query and noticed I even encounter this issue when trying to manually copy-paste the data from the power query to another Excel file. If I mouse over Values it displays the preview of the raw data, but as soon as I mouse over any of the other functions, it immediately spikes my memory to nearly 8GB usage.

Copy-Paste Dialog
[image]

Comment: You are coping full sheet, which in turn will copy its data, formatting, back-end query and i think its back-end data as well. Just copy the data and paste it in a new sheet as values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out the issue, although I'm not sure about the details:
It appears that, after running my macro dozens of times while testing my code, I was importing the same power query and all of it's connections to my workbook over and over again. I would delete the sheet I imported each time, but not the queries/connections. I'm not exactly sure how these connections work, but I presume they were all looking at and checking the destination folder for updates. I checked and realized I had nearly 60 of these queries/connections in my workbook that would presumably get triggered every time I copy-pasted the power query sheet into my workbook. Simply deleting all of these excess queries/connections resolved my issue.

If anyone knows the specifics about this process maybe clarify more in a response so future users who possibly encounter this issue will be able to resolve it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).